# (MapKit, CoreLocation) Как получить место положение пользователя не используя Map Kit View?

Tags: ios, swift

Задача состоит в том что бы получить данные пользователя( Город где он находится )распечатать их с помощью print) и отправить их на сервер, во всех примерах которые я нашла используеться  мап кит вью, а мне он в проекте не нужен, нужны только данные. Я понимаю что нужно использовать CLLocation​Manager но как правильно это реализовать не понимаю пока

Answer (score 2):

Базово. Если Вы хотите получить координаты пользователя, в Info.plist добавляете ключ `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем в Вашем классе (пример для UIViewController):

```
import CoreLocation
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    // Получаем координаты
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let coordinates = locations.last?.coordinate else {
            return
        }
        // Смотрим на координаты
        print(coordinates)
    }
    // Обрабатываете ошибки
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                         didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Далее с полученными координатами делаете все что угодно.